# C++ Any way to add a decimal point to the start of a number?

Tags: c++

So, I am supposed to make a program that asks for the value of a wholesale item, the percentage of which the item is marked up, and calculate and display the retail price using a function. The problem is I am explicitly supposed to prompt for a whole number, so if say the markup was 50%, the user should enter "50". Is there any way to just add a decimal point on the front of the 50 to simplify?

I'll include my code for clarity.

```
int main() {

    double cost;
    double markup;
    double total;

    cout << "Enter the item's wholesale cost: ";
    cin >> cost;
    cout << "\nEnter the item's markup percentage: ";
    cin >> markup;
    cout << endl;

    total = calculateRetail(cost, markup);

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    cout << "The item's retail price is $" << total << endl;

    return 0;
}

double calculateRetail(double cost, double markup)
{

    //This is where the code to convert "markup" to a decimal would go

    cost += markup * cost;

    return cost;
}
```

Comment: It's time to indent this code properly, that's for sure.

Comment: Using floating point values for monetary calculations is a sure-fire way to make a mess of things. Whenever possible used fixed-point to avoid ugly rounding errors.

Answer (score 5):

"Move the decimal point two places to the left" is the same operation as "divide the number by 100."

```
markup /= 100;
```